# Pandas index column by boolean

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, dataframe

I want to keep columns that have 'n' or more values.
For example:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [1,None,4]})

    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   NaN
2   3   4

3 rows × 2 columns

> df[df.count()==3]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

> df[:,df.count()==3]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

> df[[k for (k,v) in (df.count()==3).items() if v]]

    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Is that the best way to do this? It seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional list comprehension to generate the columns that exceed your threshold (e.g. 3).  Then just select those columns from the data frame:

```
# Create sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'b': [1, None, 4, None, 2], 
                   'c': [5, 4, 3, 2, None]})

>>> df_new = df[[col for col in df if df[col].count() > 3]]
Out[82]: 
   a   c
0  1   5
1  2   4
2  3   3
3  4   2
4  5 NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `count` to produce a boolean index and use this as a mask for the columns:

```
In [10]:

df[df.columns[df.count() > 2]]


Out[10]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

**if you want to keep columns that have 'n' or more values. for my example i am considering n value as 4**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,6], 'b': [1,None,4,5,7],'c': [1,2,3,5,8]})
print df

   a   b  c
0  1   1  1
1  2 NaN  2
2  3   4  3
3  4   5  5
4  6   7  8

print df[[i for i in xrange(0,len(df.columns)) if len(df.iloc[:,i]) - df.isnull().sum()[i] >4]]


   a  c
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
3  4  5
4  6  8
```